# How to infer type of select value as enum?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have asserted type as enum on the change event.

I wonder if this is a good way.

Any other good ways?

```js
enum Category {
  Food = "Food",
  Fashion = "Fashion",
  Device = "Device",
  All = "All",
}

const CartegorySelect = () => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState<Category>();
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setCategory(e.target.value as Category); // value is string
  }

  return (
    <select onChange={handleSelect} value={category}>
      {Object.entries(Category).map(([key, value]) => (
        <option value={value} key={key}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}
```

Comment: You might want to change `Category` into a string union instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have asserted type as enum on the change event.

That's how you do it. Typescript is not able to figure out at compile time that all the `<option>`s inside your `<select>` will have `Category`'s as their values. So since you know more than typescript does, you need to assert the type.